# How can I figure out why my MacBook is crashing?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, crash

I have a MacBook here that crashes reproducibly shortly after unplugging it from the power supply --  while it is sufficiently charged (I verified the battery charge). Battery status is healthy with few cycles.

- At first a gray screen appears informing me in several languages that a problem occured (I believe this is a kernel panic)
- Macbook reboots
- OSX asks whether it should restore the windows
- Error report is as the one from 18:0 (see below)
- It seems to be an issue with Kernel Extension com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerMAnagement

It has a 2.26 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo processor, 4 GB 1333 MHz DDR3 memory, with  NVIDIA GeForce 9400M 256 MB and OS X 10.9.2 (13C1021) installed on it.

I am a bit at loss here, since I cannot see how I can fix the problem.

**Where else could I look for crash notes? Is there something I can use for searching for crash error messages? How can I figure out what's causing my MacBook to crash like this?**

Here is the contents of one of the kernelXXXXX.panic files:

```
flags: 0x8 binding: FileInfoBinding [0x213] - extension: caf, UTI: com.apple.coreaudio-format, fileType: ????.
Jun 16 18:04:52 macbook.fritz.box quicklookd[264]: Warning: Cache image returned by the server has size range covering all valid image sizes. Binding: VariantBinding [0x1a03] flags: 0x8 binding: FileInfoBinding [0x1903] - extension: caf, UTI: com.apple.coreaudio-format, fileType: ???? request size:16 scale: 1
Jun 16 18:05:50 macbook.fritz.box Console[330]: setPresentationOptions called with NSApplicationPresentationFullScreen when there is no visible fullscreen window; this call will be ignored.
Jun 16 18:08:28 macbook kernel[0]: Sandbox: xpcd(176) deny ipc-posix-shm-read-data /tmp/com.apple.csseed.71
Jun 16 18:08:30 macbook.fritz.box com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService[341]: Bogus event received by listener connection:
     { count = 1, contents =
        "XPCErrorDescription" =>  { length = 18, contents = "Connection invalid" }
    }
Jun 16 18:09:26 macbook.fritz.box Console[330]: CGSReenableUpdateToken: invalid token 0x93fffffffff9272
Jun 16 18:09:26 macbook.fritz.box Console[330]: Backtrace (at 590.989):
Jun 16 18:09:26 macbook.fritz.box Console[330]: CGSReenableUpdateToken:  0   CoreGraphics                        0x00007fff90441a61 CGSBacktraceCreate + 59
Jun 16 18:09:26 macbook.fritz.box Console[330]: CGSReenableUpdateToken:  1   CoreGraphics                        0x00007fff9057a572 CGSLogBacktrace + 15
Jun 16 18:09:26 macbook.fritz.box Console[330]: CGSReenableUpdateToken:  2   CoreGraphics                        0x00007fff90466016 _ZN16CGSUpdateManager13enable_updateEy + 210
Jun 16 18:09:26 macbook.fritz.box Console[330]: CGSReenableUpdateToken:  3   AppKit                              0x00007fff8e4a480c __62-[NSScrollingBehaviorConcurrentVBL _stopGestureScrollTracking]_block_invoke + 313
Jun 16 18:09:26 macbook.fritz.box Console[330]: CGSReenableUpdateToken:  4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff8b9541d7 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
Jun 16 18:09:26 macbook.fritz.box Console[330]: CGSReenableUpdateToken:  5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff8b9512ad _dispatch_client_callout + 8
Jun 16 18:09:26 macbook.fritz.box Console[330]: CGSReenableUpdateToken:  6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff8b958f03 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 333
Jun 16 18:09:26 macbook.fritz.box Console[330]: CGSReenableUpdateToken:  7   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8851b5a9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
Jun 16 18:09:26 macbook.fritz.box Console[330]: CGSReenableUpdateToken:  8   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff884d67c4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1636
Jun 16 18:09:26 macbook.fritz.box Console[330]: CGSReenableUpdateToken:  9   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff884d5f25 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
Jun 16 18:09:26 macbook.fritz.box Console[330]: CGSReenableUpdateToken:  10  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8f85ca0d RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 226
Jun 16 18:09:26 macbook.fritz.box Console[330]: CGSReenableUpdateToken:  11  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8f85c7b7 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 479
Jun 16 18:09:26 macbook.fritz.box Console[330]: CGSReenableUpdateToken:  12  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8f85c5bc _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 65
Jun 16 18:09:26 macbook.fritz.box Console[330]: CGSReenableUpdateToken:  13  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e28d3de _DPSNextEvent + 1434
Jun 16 18:09:26 macbook.fritz.box Console[330]: CGSReenableUpdateToken:  14  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e28ca2b -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 122
Jun 16 18:09:26 macbook.fritz.box Console[330]: CGSReenableUpdateToken:  15  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e280b2c -[NSApplication run] + 553
Jun 16 18:09:26 macbook.fritz.box Console[330]: CGSReenableUpdateToken:  16  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e26b913 NSApplicationMain + 940
Jun 16 18:09:26 macbook.fritz.box Console[330]: CGSReenableUpdateToken:  17  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff8b6bf5fd start + 1
```

I also found a crash report for the doc that happened recently, although I do not think that it is directly connected.

Also I found those diagnostic messages

```
16.06.14 18:00:18,882 DumpPanic[50]: com.apple.message.domain: com.apple.crashreporter.writereport.panic
com.apple.message.signature: Kernel
com.apple.message.signature2: UNBUNDLED ||| 
com.apple.message.signature3: UNKNOWN
com.apple.message.result: noop
com.apple.message.summarize: YES
Sender_Mach_UUID: 3A8F5574-6B7A-31C7-BCF5-398F4125551A

16.06.14 18:00:44,543 UserEventAgent[163]: com.apple.message.domain: com.apple.usage.activity_stats
com.apple.message.apps_per_activity_min: 1.000000
com.apple.message.apps_per_activity_max: 5.000000
com.apple.message.apps_per_activity_median: 1.000000
com.apple.message.apps_per_activity_mean: 2.000000
com.apple.message.apps_per_activity_count: 9
Sender_Mach_UUID: 55428B1C-9198-32BF-80EA-4731081F402E

16.06.14 18:00:53,324 ReportPanic[226]: com.apple.message.domain: com.apple.ReportPanic.matchedpanic
com.apple.message.action: not matched and frequent
com.apple.message.panic_id: not matched
Sender_Mach_UUID: FC131E05-822D-30FF-BE6B-96CA864B9429
```

**Kernel*.panic Files**

```
Anonymous UUID:       F660CF53-8D27-469B-4782-529A7C577E90

Mon Jun 16 18:00:13 2014
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xffffff80016dbe7e): Kernel trap at 0xffffff7f8360267c, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0xffffef7f836289b8, CR3: 0x0000000004460000, CR4: 0x0000000000000660
RAX: 0x0ffffffc6f660000, RBX: 0xffffef7f836289b0, RCX: 0x0000000000000001, RDX: 0x0000003909a31661
RSP: 0xffffff807a8c3d80, RBP: 0xffffff807a8c3e70, RSI: 0x0000005909a28892, RDI: 0xffffff80741bd148
R8:  0x00000000e0000000, R9:  0x0000000000000005, R10: 0x0000000000004822, R11: 0xffffff8001c89ce8
R12: 0xffffff800c3e8000, R13: 0x0000000000000005, R14: 0xffffff80741bd148, R15: 0xffffff7f83626e20
RFL: 0x0000000000010006, RIP: 0xffffff7f8360267c, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0xffffef7f836289b8, Error code: 0x0000000000000002, Fault CPU: 0x1

Backtrace (CPU 1), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff807a8c3a10 : 0xffffff8001622fa9 
0xffffff807a8c3a90 : 0xffffff80016dbe7e 
0xffffff807a8c3c60 : 0xffffff80016f3376 
0xffffff807a8c3c80 : 0xffffff7f8360267c 
0xffffff807a8c3e70 : 0xffffff7f83601899 
0xffffff807a8c3f30 : 0xffffff80016dd73c 
0xffffff807a8c3f50 : 0xffffff80016375ba 
0xffffff807a8c3f90 : 0xffffff8001637908 
0xffffff807a8c3fb0 : 0xffffff80016d7047 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement(216.0)[70947979-EA9B-39D1-AD15-CDAB19F031AF]@0xffffff7f835ff000->0xffffff7f83629fff

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
13C1021

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 13.1.0: Wed Apr  2 23:52:02 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.92.1~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: E9CF78E2-1E9F-3B6F-81A4-FEE6C6D0E4D5
Kernel slide:     0x0000000001400000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8001600000
System model name: MacBookPro5,5 (Mac-F2268AC8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 104990528825
last loaded kext at 67055981371: com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC 1.60 (addr 0xffffff7f83230000, size 32768)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.60
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.14.15
com.apple.driver.AppleTyMCEDriver   1.0.2d2
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver   2.6.0f1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.6.0f1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothUSBDFU   4.2.3f10
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.2.3f10
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.6.0f1
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.4.35
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.2.3f10
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelMCEReporter  104
com.apple.GeForceTesla  8.2.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.13
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.3.5
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.1.12
com.apple.nvidia.NVDAStartup    8.2.4
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 35
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyEventDriver   240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  325.7
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.4.1
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.6.6
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.5.1
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   700.20.22
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBOHCI   656.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    4.9.9
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    666.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.0.0
com.apple.nvenet    2.0.21
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   660.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 216.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   153
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   216.0.0
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.4.35
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.6.0f1
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.9.5fc2
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.14
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.2.3f10
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.4.35
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.7.0d10
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   91
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.7
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.2.3f10
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla   8.2.4
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla    8.2.4
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.6.0f1
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.6.0f1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.11d1
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 240.9
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  660.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.6.6
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   650.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  656.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.6.6
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.6.6
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   630.35
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 660.4.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.6.5
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 675.4.0
com.apple.driver.NVSMU  2.2.9
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  278.11
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 371.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  23
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
```

and

```
Anonymous UUID:       F660CF53-8D27-469B-4782-529A7C577E90

Mon Jun 16 17:58:06 2014
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff80004dbe7e): Kernel trap at 0xffffef8000433660, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0xffffef8000433660, CR3: 0x0000000003260000, CR4: 0x0000000000000660
RAX: 0x000000012a05f0e5, RBX: 0x0000000000000000, RCX: 0x0000000000000000, RDX: 0x0000000000000022
RSP: 0xffffff806d062e78, RBP: 0xffffff806d062f40, RSI: 0x0000000000000000, RDI: 0xffffff800c0769e0
R8:  0x0000000000000001, R9:  0x000000002a05f0e5, R10: 0xffffff80798ebe20, R11: 0xffffff8000a89ce8
R12: 0xffffff800c076bd0, R13: 0xffffff8000ad2ab8, R14: 0xffffef8000433660, R15: 0xffffff800c0769e0
RFL: 0x0000000000010092, RIP: 0xffffef8000433660, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0xffffef8000433660, Error code: 0x0000000000000010, Fault CPU: 0x0

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff806d062b00 : 0xffffff8000422fa9 
0xffffff806d062b80 : 0xffffff80004dbe7e 
0xffffff806d062d50 : 0xffffff80004f3376 
0xffffff806d062d70 : 0xffffef8000433660 
0xffffff806d062f40 : 0xffffff80004cf3a9 
0xffffff806d062f80 : 0xffffff80004db4a9 
0xffffff806d062fd0 : 0xffffff80004f3539 
0xffffff80798ebf50 : 0xffffff80004375ba 
0xffffff80798ebf90 : 0xffffff8000437908 
0xffffff80798ebfb0 : 0xffffff80004d7047 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
13C1021

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 13.1.0: Wed Apr  2 23:52:02 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.92.1~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: E9CF78E2-1E9F-3B6F-81A4-FEE6C6D0E4D5
Kernel slide:     0x0000000000200000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8000400000
System model name: MacBookPro5,5 (Mac-F2268AC8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 369999185637
last loaded kext at 284869466259: com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs 1.9 (addr 0xffffff7f827f7000, size 65536)
last unloaded kext at 346085278918: com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs   1.9 (addr 0xffffff7f827f7000, size 57344)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 2.0.1
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.60
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.14.15
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.6.0f1
com.apple.GeForceTesla  8.2.4
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.2.3f10
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.13
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.6.0f1
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.2.3f10
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.3.5
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.1.12
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  240.2
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 35
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  325.7
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.4.1
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.6.6
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.5.1
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   700.20.22
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    666.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    4.9.9
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.0.0
com.apple.nvenet    2.0.21
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   660.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBOHCI   656.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 216.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   153
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   216.0.0
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.4.35
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.6.0f1
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.9.5fc2
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.14
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.2.3f10
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla   8.2.4
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla    8.2.4
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.6.0f1
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.6.0f1
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.7.0d10
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   91
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.7
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.2.3f10
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.11d1
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 240.9
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  660.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.6.6
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   650.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  656.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.6.6
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.6.6
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   630.35
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 660.4.2
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.6.5
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 675.4.0
com.apple.driver.NVSMU  2.2.9
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  278.11
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 371.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  23
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
```

```
Anonymous UUID:       F660CF53-8D27-469B-4782-529A7C577E90

Mon Jun 16 17:51:36 2014
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff8008adbe7e): Kernel trap at 0xffffff7f8aa0267c, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0xffffef7f8aa289b0, CR3: 0x000000000b860000, CR4: 0x0000000000000660
RAX: 0x0ffffffcf4760000, RBX: 0xffffef7f8aa289b0, RCX: 0x0000000000000000, RDX: 0x00000030b8a1c2e5
RSP: 0xffffff8081663d80, RBP: 0xffffff8081663e70, RSI: 0x00000050b8a0d8ae, RDI: 0xffffff807566f148
R8:  0x00000000e0000000, R9:  0x0000000000000005, R10: 0x00000000000003ff, R11: 0xffffffffffffffff
R12: 0xffffff8013b71000, R13: 0x0000000000000005, R14: 0xffffff807566f148, R15: 0xffffff7f8aa26e20
RFL: 0x0000000000010006, RIP: 0xffffff7f8aa0267c, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0xffffef7f8aa289b0, Error code: 0x0000000000000002, Fault CPU: 0x0

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff8081663a10 : 0xffffff8008a22fa9 
0xffffff8081663a90 : 0xffffff8008adbe7e 
0xffffff8081663c60 : 0xffffff8008af3376 
0xffffff8081663c80 : 0xffffff7f8aa0267c 
0xffffff8081663e70 : 0xffffff7f8aa01899 
0xffffff8081663f30 : 0xffffff8008add73c 
0xffffff8081663f50 : 0xffffff8008a375ba 
0xffffff8081663f90 : 0xffffff8008a37908 
0xffffff8081663fb0 : 0xffffff8008ad7047 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement(216.0)[70947979-EA9B-39D1-AD15-CDAB19F031AF]@0xffffff7f8a9ff000->0xffffff7f8aa29fff

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
13C1021

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 13.1.0: Wed Apr  2 23:52:02 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.92.1~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: E9CF78E2-1E9F-3B6F-81A4-FEE6C6D0E4D5
Kernel slide:     0x0000000008800000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8008a00000
System model name: MacBookPro5,5 (Mac-F2268AC8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 139817506301
last loaded kext at 48799877244: com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC 1.60 (addr 0xffffff7f8a630000, size 32768)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.60
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AppleTyMCEDriver   1.0.2d2
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.14.15
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver   2.6.0f1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.6.0f1
com.apple.GeForceTesla  8.2.4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothUSBDFU   4.2.3f10
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.2.3f10
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.13
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.6.0f1
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.2.3f10
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelMCEReporter  104
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.4.35
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.3.5
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.1.12
com.apple.nvidia.NVDAStartup    8.2.4
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyEventDriver   240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  325.7
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 35
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.4.1
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.6.6
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.5.1
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   700.20.22
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    666.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    4.9.9
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.0.0
com.apple.nvenet    2.0.21
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   660.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBOHCI   656.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 216.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   153
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   216.0.0
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.4.35
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.6.0f1
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.9.5fc2
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.14
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.2.3f10
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla   8.2.4
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla    8.2.4
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.6.0f1
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.6.0f1
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.7.0d10
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   91
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.7
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.2.3f10
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.4.35
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.11d1
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 240.9
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  660.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.6.6
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   650.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  656.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.6.6
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.6.6
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   630.35
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 660.4.2
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.6.5
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 675.4.0
com.apple.driver.NVSMU  2.2.9
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  278.11
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 371.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  23
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
```

Comment: Great that you have worked hard to diagnose it yourself, but the question is missing some basic essential info.  What do you mean by **crash**?  Is it spontaneously rebooting?  Just hanging?  Showing an error?  A mix?

Comment: Its a reboot. However i have not observed it myself and will try to provoke the issue

Comment: I was able to reproduce the error on the spot. I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Shooting form the HIP.. your battery is reporting the wrong state, so system tries to change the power to the CPU (that would be normal), so please use the ALT key and click on the Battery before and during the problem.

Comment: Do you mean pressing the alt key and Battery symbol in the toolbar? I am not sure that i know what i should ovserve while the problem occurs

Answer (score 3):

I would recomend following steps in trouble shooting:

If you start in safe mode (hold Shift during start up) that would eliminate 3d party applications doing it.

If no problems, then some 3rd-party thing is causing the problem.

If problems also in Safe mode, then most likely hardware related.

Run the Apple Hardware Test suite (hold D during start up), extended tests at least twice.

Under normal operation when Battery is weak or falsely reporting its state the system will cut the CPU power in half. That should not force the restart but it is possible.

Reset your SMC and PRAM to verify that.

In you logs i did not find the culprit (it is hiding well).

Feel free to publish some 50 lines before the boot-time (enter it in the Filter window of the Console)

Comment: I have not yet been able to run safe modr but i have observed another, different crash pastebin.com/DJaT2wXr

Comment: It seems to happe  when opening a web browser (safari, firefox) . when idle i cannot observe the crashing

Comment: No. Solely osx.

Comment: I was just wondering about loaded kext at 282717765047: com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs 1.9 Did you use a USB stick ? with msdosfs format

Comment: No usb stick and no fat partition. However word 2004 and 2008 are installed.

Comment: D is not safe-mode. It's AHT mode. Use shift instead.